# What is the $id field in my Json response using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework

Why would my object (that doesn't include the $id, be adding it to my Json response?)

Json Response:

[image]

Model:

```
public class DivisionWithProductsViewModel
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Description {get;set;}
   public string Thumbnail {get;set;}
   public string ThumbnailName {get;set;}
   public List<ProductViewModel> ProductList {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: It is probably an internal index of JSON message

Comment: Firstly, please provide text of source code, not images. Secondly, how are you serialising the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$id` and `$ref` fields are used to make an object hierarchy in JSON.

See this JSON for example:

```
{
   "people":[
      {
         "$id":1,
         "name":"John",
         "children":[
            { "$ref":2 }
         ]
      },
      {
         "$id":2,
         "name":"Jane"
      }
   ]
}
```

The object in list `children` will be the exact same as the object used when deserializing `Jane`.

If you deserialize that using JSON.NET, and you change the name of `Jane`, it will updated the 'child' Jane too since it is the same object reference.